# A question on a limit arising in Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation

Let $$a_k = \frac{1}{k\pi}\sum_{j=0}^m\alpha_j\sin(kT_j)$$ $\alpha_j,T_j \in \mathbb{R}, 0<T_j<\pi,m \in \mathbb{N}$.

I'd like to know the limit if it exists,  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log(n)}\sum_{k=1}^n\left|a_k\right|$$

Comment: If $x_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|}{\log(n)}$ then using $|a_n| \leq \frac{C}{n}$ we get that $x_n$ is bounded. Unfortunately $x_n$ is not monotone in general. It's tempting to try Stolz–Cesàro however this leads to a limit which does not exist in general so not very helpful. Probabilistic methods might be useful. If $m=0$ and $X = (kT_0 \mod 2\pi)/2\pi$ is treated as a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$ then since $E[|\sin(2\pi X)|] = \frac{2}{\pi}$ we should have something like $\frac{2|\alpha_0|}{\pi^2}$ if the limit exist (and $T_0$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$).

Comment: @Winther Can this be useful, creates some hope: $$\int_0^{\lambda}\left|\frac{\sin t}t\right|dt \sim C\log(\lambda)$$

Comment: Can we say : $$\int_0^{\lambda}\left|\frac{A\sin(at) + B\sin(bt) + C\sin(ct)}t\right|dt \sim K\log(\lambda)$$